# perfino doesn't show any call tree, hot spots

Tags: perfino

I'm using an evaluation version of perfino and able to start my java application with the agent.
The server is able to show VM's basic telemetries e.g. Used Heap, CPU.
However, I don't see anything show up in the 'VM Data Views'->'Transactions'->'Call Tree' or 'Hot Spots'

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure your transactions. The configuration can be accessed like this:

- Click the settings button in the top-right corner
- Select Recording & Triggers
- Double-click on the "Transactions" column of the "All VMs" VM group (or for whatever group you want to configure)

By default, perfino converts URL invocations, RMI calls, Spring service calls and EJB calls into transactions. If your applications does not use any of those subsystems, you will not see any transactions.

In that case, you can use the "POJO invocations" or the "DevOps annotated invocations" to convert any method call into a transaction. They are both equivalent, for "POJO invocations" you specify the methods in the perfino UI, for "DevOps annotated invocations" you use annotations provided by perfino, see

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/perfino/help/api/doc/

For a better understanding of transactions, I would recommend to read

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/perfino/help/doc/main/transactions.html

Comment: Thank you much for your prompt reply. I can read the code however I can't alter the code so "DevOps..." option is not possible. I tried the "POJO..." options and can't get it to work either. There are quite many classes in the application and set the transaction per the link that you forwarded (it's quite helpful). I picked few that are relevant, however, still nothing show up. Also I'm getting these exceptions: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out...

Comment: Do you have a connection from the VM in the VMs view?

Comment: Yes. I do have a connection

Comment: Please let me know if i'm incorrectly adding the transaction: 'Recording & Triggers' ->Click on one of the VM-> Click on the pencil icon ->In 'Edit Group Configuration' Click on + sign and slect 'Pojo invocation' -> In 'Create Pojo Invocation' check 'Class or interface' and 'Intercept subclasses' -> in 'Class name' field select 'Browse classes in connected JVMs' ->drill all the way down to one of the class and select it.-> take all the defaults and hit Next button